# Staying in Romania for longer than 90 days with two passports

Tags: dual-nationality, romania

I have both US and UK passports. I’m considering visiting Romania for longer than 90 days. Can I do this by entering on one passport, staying the allowed 90 days, exiting, and entering the next day on the other passport?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can **or** allowed? Allowed it is not, since the rules are based on the fact that you are a **third-country national** and may only stay no more than 90 days in any 180-day period. That is one reason why systems such as the [Entry/Exit System (EES)](https://www.etiasvisa.com/etias-news/ees-europe-etias-visa), that will collect your biometric information, are being introduced to prevent such a missuse.

Answer (score 9):

No. The limit is always, everywhere, for a person, not for a passport.

While the only way they have to enforce it at the moment is checking the stamps in your passport, and they could thus not notice you are over the limit, if they do find out you would be in trouble.

Also note that Romania will finally be part of Schengen from March 31st (with land border checks maintained for now), and thus the whole time in any Schengen Area country counts towards your 90 days.

If you need to stay longer you probably need a national visa allowing it. Which one depends on your circumstances, especially the reason why you need to stay that long.